# Excel data change, Java does not notice

Tags: java, excel

I have a stupid problem.
I'm automating some tests with selenium, some data is in excel sheets (It was like that, I'll change it, I promise :p)
Some of the fields are dropdowns, I can change them and everything is OK. Others are regular text, if I change them my ExcelReader class just dont notice it and pick the old value.
I'm no excel expert (I dont have much idea about it) but anyone can guess a possible cause for this?

Note: I'm not checking for changes in real time. I'm doing different executions and observing data no to change

Comment: Where does this `ExcelReader` class come from? Did you write it? If so, what library does it use to read the spreadsheets?

Comment: I wrote it, it uses JExcelApi WorkBook and Sheet clases: http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are doing this:

1. Opening spreadsheet via Microsoft Excel
2. Opening spreadsheet via your `ExcelReader` class
3. Making a change to the spreadsheet via Microsoft Excel
4. You are **not** noticing the change via your `ExcelReader` class

If so, I believe that JExcelApi (along with most other Excel libraries) will only read the spreadsheet file **once**. That is, it will not keep in sync with any changes occurring in the file over time. You may have to create a thread to keep an eye on the file's last modified date and re-read it when that date changes.

```
new Thread(
        new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                File file = new File("/path/to/your/spreadsheet");
                long previouslyLastModified = file.lastModified();
                while (true) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000); // 1000 milliseconds == 1 second
                    long lastModified = file.lastModified();
                    if (lastModified != previouslyLastModified) {
                        // Reload the spreadsheet
                    }
                    previouslyLastModified = lastModified;
                }
            }
        }
    ).start();
```

Of course, there are probably some libraries out there that do a much better job of watching a file for changes. Java itself doesn't come with the functionality to watch a file ([although it is included in Java 7](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)).

Comment: I'm not checking for changes in real time. I'm doing different executions and observing data no to change :S